# Is there a to export RealityKit scene to USDZ?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, realitykit, usdz

I have a RealityKit scene I would Like to export to and file format (preferably to USDZ) I haven’t found any solution for it. I know it is possible to do with SceneKit but not RealityKit.

Comment: I've submitted a request to Apple for this to be added to the API but nothing still

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Reality Converter app, just drop in a file in(ex. obj or dae) and it'll convert it to USDZ format. You can also customize your 3D models on it so it's pretty sweet. You can check it out here: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01132020a